# How to set valid DOM property through input property binding in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

As per my understanding In Angular through Square brackets(input property binding) we set DOM properties of an HTML element.

Here, in the below example this is a valid way of changing font-size through input property binding in Angular.

```
<p [style.fontSize.px]="500" id="targeted">first-component works!</p>
```

But, this `style.fontSize.px` doesn't seems to be a valid DOM property because something like this won't work in JS.

```
document.getElementById("targeted").style.fontSize.px = '50'
```

So, then how font-size can change through this in Angular `<p [style.fontSize.px]="500" id="targeted">first-component works!</p>` if this `style.fontSize.px` is not a valid DOM property?

And can I get an explanation on how this `style.fontSize.px` can work in Angular?

Comment: You're right, this is not a valid DOM prop. Angular just helps you by adding such a directive that makes some work under the hood. So as a result it parses `[style.fontSize.px]="500"` to `[style.fontSize]="500 + 'px'"`. You can find more info here in the doc  https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#single-and-multiple-style-binding-example

Comment: You can learn the implementation in the [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e4aee2b83d510c91335d1b4314ec9f7b6d4a4e5b/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts) if you want to know how it works

Comment: @MaxMartynov how the source you attached is applicable for this example. As I am referring to [style] and it's referring to ngStyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR answering your question:

> So, then how font-size can change through this in Angular `<p [style.fontSize.px]="500" id="targeted">first-component works!</p>` if
> this `style.fontSize.px` is not a valid DOM property?

It's because you use the Angular's [binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#binding-types-and-targets) (square brackets) that handles the input value `[style.fontSize.px]="500"` and turns it into valid HTML attributes & CSS properties `style="font-size: 500px;"`

### About the square brackets

> As per my understanding In Angular through Square brackets(input property binding) we set DOM properties of an HTML element.

That's not completely correct. The square brackets mean using a directive. Things in square brackets are (almost) never just HTML attributes and they will be handled by the directive's handler. Don't be confused. The fact that directives use the same names as known HTML attributes doesn't mean these attributes will be used in the result DOM as they are. The result value always depends on the directive's logic.

That's why you should look for the answer to your question somewhere in the Angular directives. And start from the binding syntax:
https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#binding-types-and-targets

### How it works

> And can I get an explanation on how this style.fontSize.px can work in Angular?

You can learn the [sources of the ngStyle directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e4aee2b83d510c91335d1b4314ec9f7b6d4a4e5b/packages/common/src/directives/ng_style.ts#L81) that works similarly to `[style]` with only one difference: `[ngStyle]` supports only object literal syntax and it cannot support strings or single values like `[style]` does. Here you can see how the directive turns the input expression `style.fontSize.px` into valid HTML attributes.

If you want to really dig into the sources of the [[style]](https://angular.io/api/animations/style) directive, you have to learn this lib [@angular/animations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/animations) which is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/15.2.3/packages/animations/src/animation_metadata.ts#L749-L792)

Answer (score 1):

Angular [templates](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) is a form of an extended HMTL that would be rendered to regular HTML, as the [documentation describes](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#template-syntax) it:

> A template looks like regular HTML, except that it also contains Angular [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), which alters the HTML based on your application's logic and the state of application and DOM data. Your template can use data binding to coordinate the application and DOM data, pipes to transform data before it is displayed, and directives to apply application logic to what gets displayed.

So in your example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qugq1z?file=src%2Fmain.ts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: ` <p [style.fontSize.px]="50" id="targeted">first-component works!</p>
  `,
})
export class App {}
```

This template with its [style binding](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#binding-to-a-single-style) would be rendered to a valid "browser-friendly" HTML/CSS codes:

```
<p id="targeted" style="font-size: 50px;">first-component works!</p>
```